# NUnit | .NET | Test a method with needs a object with constructor which creates new object

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I am trying to test in NUnit a method MonthCost(Ticket ticket) which needs one parameter - object Ticket -  that has a constructor which creates a new object cnf.  NUnit throws me an System.NullReferenceException because the Nunit framework has a problem with that constructor (I am not able to mock this Ticket object because it is an old code with no chance for deep refactoring). I get the exception in the process of creation of cnf object. How to omit that problem? How to test this MonthCost method()?

```
    public class Ticket(){
        public Ticket()
          {
             Configuration cnf = new Configuration(param1, param2);
          }
        public string Price { get; set; }
          }

    [Test]
    public void CalculateTicketsMonthTest()
    {
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
        humanService.MonthCost(ticket);
    }
```

I made an research on stackoverflow and debuged that code. I tried differend code configurations. Nothing helps.

Comment: if you cannot fake a dependency, you have to provide it as usual. What problem do you have doing that? How should we know where exactly you get the exception when you don't provide any information about how those objects look like?

Comment: it's not the framework having a problem with the constructor, it's that your test-env does not fit your normal process-flow. Having said this I assume you need a valid `Configuration` - whatever that actually is.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain But in that case, new Ticket(new Whatever(new ...)) you are telling the Object that it has an constructor with an parameter. . My has zero parameters :(

Comment: Yes, you should try to refactor it so you can provide the dependency from the outside and evantually mock it. However as it is there's no other way as providing a complete configuration as well

Comment: we cannot know, as we have no clue about what a `Configuration` is and how it usually is created. I suppose you need to debug your actual app to see how the config works and what you need to provide an instance of it within your test.